# How to post nested lists of IFormFile in .NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-apicontroller

I am working to an ASP.NET Core Web API project (.NET 7.0). I am trying to build an endpoint to send data along with files. The `Post` controller action accepts an instance of the `ParentDto` class. This class contains a list of `ChildDto`, each one having a string value, a collection of `IFormFile` and an optional list of children of the same type.

```
public class ParentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChildDto> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDto
{
    public string? Value { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile>? Files { get; set; }
    public List<ChildDto>? Children { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] ParentDto dto)
    {
        // Controller code...
    }
}
```

When I send data with Postman along with files, the `Files` property is populated only for the first level of the hierarchy. The `children[0][children][0].files` property is null, while all others are correctly populated. Even if I add more than one child to the `ParentDto.Children` property, the lists of files are handled correctly for each child. The problem seems to be in the nested list.

[image: Data sent to the Post endpoint]

Comment: "The `children[0][children][0].files` property is null' is not null.

Comment: The property is null in the Dto

Comment: Have a look at this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzlOc.gif

Comment: Thank you Qing, so there is something wrong with the data I send with Postman probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My postman picture like:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: The key format I used in Postman is wrong, thank you